Line of code not compiling in jupyter notebook
I'm trying to build a second dataframe in Jupyter Notebook to train a stronger model.
This is the line of code:
dtc2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', ccp_alpha=0.04)

I'm getting a type error:

TyperError: init() got an unexpected keyword arugment 'ccp_alpha'

Which is odd because ccp alpha should be a standard jupyter notebook keyword. Please let me know if you have any solutions!
Thank you!
I tried writing:
dtc2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', ccp_alpha=0.04)

Which should be standard line of code to build a dataframe.

Please be kind to everyone regardless of experience level or the questions they ask. @9769953

@sonofjupyter Sorry, I don't understand: what are you referring to (if anything at all)?

Referring to your comments. @9769953

Ah, you mean my first comment. Sorry, that was just meant as a correction, but I can see that the phrasing isn't that good, and it can be interpreted differently. I'll replace it by a better version.

Note that ccc_alpha is not a standard Jupyter notebook keyword (in fact, Jupyter notebooks don't really have keywords). It's a parameter of the scikit-learn class DecisionTreeClassifier.

As per the documentation, ccp_alpha is new since version 0.22 of scikit-learn.
Double check your version of scikit-learn, and upgrade as necessary.
